# Trigger event in Google Analytics from Server side

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

We're trying to see if we can create a "Goal" in Google Analytics view that will get triggered when certain event takes place - on the Server - NOT on the Website. For example, when a customer service representative makes a "call" to a "customer" we want to record it as an "event" in GA.

I've created a new Goal in GA called, "Call_Held" with type "Event". The "Event Condition" is "Action" Equals to "CALL_HELD".

Next step is to call "some" GA API to create this Event when an event is recorded on the server side. This API will be called from a Python program. Is there such an API available? Is this the right way to use Google Analytics? This is the first time we're trying to use GA "Goals" from server side.